# Multiple Sign In cancelled in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I've builb a simple chat app using Firebase, but it allows only one sign in at a time. For example: **If my friend install my app on his phone and tries to sign in with his gmail account, he gets a toast message of sign in cancelled. Further if I sign out from my phone, then he is able to sign in.** My rules tab in firebase is set to default i.e. "auth != null". I'm unable to figure out what is causing this problem. Please help.
Below is my Authentication code.

```
    authStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
                public static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 1;

                @Override
                public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

                    if (user != null) {
                        OnsigninInitialize(user.getDisplayName());
                    } else {
                        OnsignoutClean();
                        startActivityForResult(
                                AuthUI.getInstance()
                                        .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                                        .setProviders(
                                                Arrays.asList(new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.EMAIL_PROVIDER).build(),

                                                        new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER).build()
                                                ))
                                        .build(),
                                RC_SIGN_IN);
                    }
                }
            };

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if(requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN){
                if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Signed In! WELCOME",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
                    Toast.makeText(this, "SignIn Cancelled!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish();
                }
  }
}
```

Since it is chat app, I want that it should allow multiple sign in.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask You should provide some code, explain what you want to do, and describe what results you get.

Comment: @jdv Is it ok now?